# How do I convert a JWK to an Ethereum Public & Private Key?

Tags: secp256k1

I'm generating a P-256K key pair using Azure Key Vault & it returns it in JWK format.

I don't know a lot about cryptography, but I need to convert this to a public & private key in the Ethereum format of hexadecimal using JavaScript.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is an example of an Ethereum private & public key:

Public: `0xBcd4042DE499D14e55001CcbB24a551F3b954096`
Private: `f214f2b2cd398c806f84e317254e0f0b801d0643303237d97a22a48e01628897`